# Webform submission redirect to view with node ID

Tags: 7, webforms

I have a view with table of data about a member of a sport club. I've placed a link to webform in the header that adds more rows into that view, which works fine but I'd like to redirect the form to go back to that view with person's ID as the argument/token.
To make it more straightforward: my view is `/grade-details/%id`, webform pickups the ID and inserts new data into right person table.

How can I make the redirection to go back to the view with same person details?

Answer (score 0):

If it's anything like Drupal 8, tokens are supported if you pick the "URL (redirects to a custom path or URL)" confirmation type.

I'd try entering /grade-details/[token:here]

Some tokens that might work:
[current-page:url:absolute]
or
[current-page:url:relative]